# Can't boot into recovery or TWRP

Tags: twrp, unbricking, motorola-moto-g

Long story short, I was trying to get TWRP on my Moto G6 but am unable to boot in any way.

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```

Results in the phone hanging with the Motorola logo. I'm **guessing** that this is relating to me flashing the recovery before-hand instead of booting it first. I'm not sure, I'm new to this.

When I try to boot into recovery from fastboot it presents me with the fastboot screen once more saying *"Start Up Failed"* with an error *"Failed to pass validaton [sic], backup to fastboot"*.

For the record, the normal mode boots up fine, but I don't really care for the phone if I can't get TWRP running on it.

Comment: Is your bootloader locked?

Comment: Tried booting to recovery using ADB commands? `adb reboot recovery`?